# Map failing to be provided to Angular Leaflet sidebar component when not using custom event

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

Consider a very simple Angular 11 application using the [@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) and [@runette/ngx-leaflet-sidebar](https://github.com/runette/ngx-leaflet-sidebar) packages. My goal is just to properly display an empty sidebar.

### The working example

A working example is provided by [this tutorial](https://medium.com/runic-software/advanced-interactive-maps-in-angular-with-leaflet-68baafa03f72) (which unfortunately fails when run on Angular 11 because of some missing types references and some wrong property definitions, but you can find the fixed and simplified code [here](https://github.com/michelezamuner/leaflet-tutorial)).

The example defines a custom component `osm-map` to hold some details about the map:

```html
<!-- app/osm-map/osm-map.component.html -->
<div class="map-container" leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="options"
  (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
></div>
```

the interesting part here is that the original event `leafletMapReady` that is generated by the third-party Leaflet component is captured by the `onMapReady()` component method, which just stores the map that has been produced, and generates a new event to notify the rest of the application of the presence of the new map:

```js
// app/osm-map/osm-map.component.ts
...
@Output() map$: EventEmitter<Map> = new EventEmitter();
public map: Map;
...
onMapReady(map: Map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.map$.emit(map);
}
```

The custom `osm-map` component is then used by the root `app` component, which also defines the sidebar control:

```html
<!-- app/app.component.html -->
<app-osm-map
  [options]="mapOptions"
  (map$)="receiveMap($event)"
></app-osm-map>

<leaflet-sidebar-control
  [map]="map"
  [options]="sidebarOptions"
></leaflet-sidebar-control>

<div id="sidebar" class="leaflet-sidebar collapsed">
  ...
</div>
```

the interesting thing here is that we register the `receiveMap()` method as a listener for the custom `map$` event generated by the `osm-map` component. This listener does nothing more than updating the `map` component property that is bound to the `map` property of the `leaflet-sidebar-control` component:

```js
// app/app.component.ts
...
public map: Map;
...
receiveMap(map: Map) {
  this.map = map;
}
```

### The not-working example

Starting from the example described previously, I just want to do this: move the code from the `osm-map` component to the root `app` component.

My idea is really simple: instead of getting the map from the Leaflet event and then sending it again via another custom event before it's bound to the Leaflet sidebar, I can just get the map from Leaflet and bind it immediately to the sidebar:

```html
<!-- app/app.component.html -->
<div class="map-container" leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="mapOptions"
  (leafletMapReady)="receiveMap($event)"
></div>

<leaflet-sidebar-control
  [map]="map"
  [options]="sidebarOptions"
></leaflet-sidebar-control>
```

```js
// app/app.component.ts
...
public map: Map;
...
receiveMap(map: Map) {
  this.map = map;
}
```

However, this doesn't work: the sidebar is not properly registered with the map, its HTML is not moved under the map element, and it's not displayed correctly to the right.

My impression is that there's something I don't understand regarding the way the map is bound to the Leaflet sidebar: perhaps the way the second example is doing it, the binding is done before the map is actually generated or something like that?